# rabbitmq-plugins does not see erlang version

Tags: rabbitmq, asdf-vm

how to enable rabbitmq plugin?
I use asdf for manage versions. But rabbitmq-plugins does not see erlang version

```
sudo su
asdf current erlang && rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
21.2.4  (set by /home/mvalitov/.tool-versions)
No version set for erlang; please run `asdf <global | local> erlang <version>`
```

UPD:

```
 mvalitov@mvalitov-pc  ~  asdf global erlang 21.2.4  
 mvalitov@mvalitov-pc  ~  sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
No version set for erlang; please run `asdf <global | local> erlang <version>`
 mvalitov@mvalitov-pc  ~  sudo asdf global erlang 21.2.4                  
 mvalitov@mvalitov-pc  ~  sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
No version set for erlang; please run `asdf <global | local> erlang <version>`
 mvalitov@mvalitov-pc  ~  asdf current erlang
21.2.4  (set by /home/mvalitov/.tool-versions)
 mvalitov@mvalitov-pc  ~  sudo asdf current erlang
21.2.4  (set by /home/mvalitov/.tool-versions)
 mvalitov@mvalitov-pc  ~  erl
Erlang/OTP 21 [erts-10.2.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe]

Eshell V10.2.3  (abort with ^G)
1> 
User switch command
 --> 
BREAK: (a)bort (c)ontinue (p)roc info (i)nfo (l)oaded
       (v)ersion (k)ill (D)b-tables (d)istribution
a
 mvalitov@mvalitov-pc  ~  sudo erl
Erlang/OTP 21 [erts-10.2.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe]

Eshell V10.2.3  (abort with ^G)
1> 
BREAK: (a)bort (c)ontinue (p)roc info (i)nfo (l)oaded
       (v)ersion (k)ill (D)b-tables (d)istribution
```

asdf v0.5.1

Linux my-pc 4.20.17-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Mar 19 18:07:36 UTC 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: The output is telling you exactly what to do, run `asdf <global | local> erlang <version>`

Comment: @LukeBakken of course it was done

Comment: Saying "of course it was done" doesn't really tell me anything. Please run that command, and then paste the text from your terminal showing the command you ran as well as its output.

Comment: @LukeBakken , I added text

Comment: About a year ago I already encountered such a problem, and created an issue in github. Then the problem was solved by itself, the next day. As I understand it, the thing is in asdf

Answer (score 0):

There have been numerous bug fixes in the versions that have been released since version `0.5.1`. Please upgrade to asdf `0.7.4` and regenerate the shims:

```
asdf reshim
```